# Ubuntu on HP Pavilion x360 convertible 14-dw0997nz

Tags: boot, usb, hp-pavilion

[SOLVED] I want to install Ubuntu on my HP Pavilion x360 convertible 14-dw0997nz.
Unfortunately it does not boot from USB (The same stick works in other laptops).

Many tutorials mention to enable "Legacy boot". But this option is not avialable in the new bios??? See picture. [Legacy ??](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a05fE.jpg)

Any Ideas how to install Ubuntu on a new HP Pavilion?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was not Linux.

First I had to create a bootable Stick using **GPT** (not msdos).

Second, I had to login into Windows, and then searching in the configuration for the **reboot from stick** option. Unfortunately I can not reproduce the procedure, hence my #@!%-M$Windows is fortunately gone forever! (For that, I had to create a Windows account only to delete windows: funny, isn't it?)